# Where is the right location for the script, so that it runs once after system power up?

Tags: zsh, startup, xorg

In my `~/.zshrc` I have something like this:

```
# map capslock to escape
ps cax | grep xcape > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  # do nothing
else
  xmodmap ~/.xmodmap & xcape &
fi
```

This appears to be working on system power up, however after my computer goes to standby and awakes, I lose that binding, so my `CAPS LOCK` stops behaving like `CTRL` or `ESC`. I tried putting this script in many locations, including `~/.zprofile` and similar to no avail. My system is arch linux (Antergos distro), with GNOME 3 as a desktop environment.

REVISED:

Looks like the right way of doing it in Arch linux, is by making a service which will do the task on resume. As this guide says: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Sleep_hooks

However, I am not sure, how would I start that `resume@.service`, as it doesn't have the usual name? `systemctl start resume@.service` won't work here, I am afraid.
EDIT:

Just found out, that this is so called template unit file, so I guess I just have to pass in the username as argument, that will be put in place of `User=%I` line...?

I have adjusted the script from that page, to my own needs and it looks like below now. But it does not work. Any thoughts on this one?

```
/etc/systemd/system/resume@.service

[Unit]
Description=User resume actions
After=suspend.target

[Service]
User=%I
Type=oneshot
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
; ExecStartPre=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/xmodmap ~/.xmodmap & /usr/bin/xcape &"

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

`journalctl -xe` gives this, so I guess the service started, but no effects of `xmodmap` and `xcape` are seen.

```
Sep 10 19:23:44 antergos systemd[1]: Starting User resume actions...
-- Subject: Unit resume@branchito.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit resume@branchito.service has begun starting up.
Sep 10 19:23:44 antergos systemd[1]: Started User resume actions.
-- Subject: Unit resume@branchito.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit resume@branchito.service has finished starting up.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `~/.zshrc` is not a great place for this to live; that will
invoke your xmodmap (a global X setting) command every time you start
a new shell.  (What you're doing may actually already work if you
simply fire up a new shell each time your system *wakes*.)

A better solution would be to have this invoked only on boot and
wake/resume.  You should be able to accomplish that by putting the
`xmodmap` line into a tiny ***p**ower **m**anagement* script in
`/etc/pm/sleep.d/`.  You'll also want it in your `~/.xinitrc` for X
start-up.

Some more discussion on this
[here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/how-to-run-a-script-on-wake-up-from-sleep-state-940311/).